# Javascript: Finding an object's index in an array, not knowing the index, only the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

I have an array of objects and I want to remove one of the objects.

```
[
  {"field":"ingredients","gte":"egg","lte":"egg"},
  {"field":"ingredients","gte":"bakepulver","lte":"bakepulver"},
  {"field":"ingredients","gte":"hvetemel","lte":"hvetemel"}
]
```

I don't know the index of the object I want to remove, but I know the whole object. I.e:

```
{"field":"ingredients","gte":"bakepulver","lte":"bakepulver"}
```

I need to find the object's index by it's full content (all properties), not just by `field`, `gte` or `lte`. How do I find object's index in the array with just plain JavaScript?

Comment: what is unique among all these objects?

Comment: Can your object have any properties that are objects/arrays themselves? (nested)

Comment: [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)!

Comment: @user2181397 The combination of `field`, `gte`and `lte`. And `gte` and `lte` can be different from each other.

Comment: @Bergi findIndex doesn't work on the whole object, and the uniqueness of the objects are the combination of object property values.

Comment: @trincot No, only three key/value pairs: `field`, `gte` and `lte`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the data and then check the length of the keys and every key, if it has the same content.

```js
var data = [{ "field": "ingredients", "gte": "egg", "lte": "egg" }, { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" }, { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "hvetemel", "lte": "hvetemel" }],
    search = { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" },
    keys = Object.keys(search),
    index = -1;

data.some(function (a, i) {
    if (Object.keys(a).length === keys.length && keys.every(function (k) { return a[k] === search[k]; })) {
        index = i;
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(index);
```

ES6

```js
var data = [{ "field": "ingredients", "gte": "egg", "lte": "egg" }, { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" }, { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "hvetemel", "lte": "hvetemel" }],
    search = { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" },
    keys = Object.keys(search),
    index = data.findIndex(a =>
        Object.keys(a).length === keys.length && keys.every(k => a[k] === search[k]));

console.log(index);
```

Comment: What is the reason of using `Array.prototype.some` just for iteration? (instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`)

Comment: it ends the iteration if the first matched object is found. `forEach` iterates all items of the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz you probably meant to `return true` inside the `if` if you want `some` to end early. The current code will return the last matching index.

Comment: And it's working really well! Great answer. I'm using the ES6 version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.findIndex()`, `Array.prototype.every()` to check if each property name, value, and object property names `.length` are equal.

```js
let data = [
  {"field":"ingredients","gte":"egg","lte":"egg"},
  {"field":"ingredients","gte":"bakepulver","lte":"bakepulver"},
  {"field":"ingredients","gte":"hvetemel","lte":"hvetemel"}
];

let props = {"field":"ingredients","gte":"bakepulver","lte":"bakepulver"};
let keys = Object.keys(props);
let index = data.findIndex(o => keys.every(key => o[key] === props[key]) 
              && Object.keys(o).length === keys.length);

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your further comments, you need a solution for this specific case only, where the objects consist of 3 given properties. Therefore I would suggest this ES6 solution:

```js
var data = [
  { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "egg", "lte": "egg" },
  { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" },
  { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "hvetemel", "lte": "hvetemel" }];
var search = { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" };

var index = data.findIndex(
    a => a.field == search.field && a.gte == search.gte && a.lte == search.lte);

console.log(index);
```

If you don't have full ES6 support, then:

```js
var data = [
  { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "egg", "lte": "egg" },
  { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" },
  { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "hvetemel", "lte": "hvetemel" }];
var search = { "field": "ingredients", "gte": "bakepulver", "lte": "bakepulver" };

var index = -1;
data.some(function (a, i) {
    if (a.field == search.field && a.gte == search.gte && a.lte == search.lte)
        return index = i, true;
});
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code for your problem

```
var array = [
    {"field":"ingredients","gte":"egg","lte":"egg"},
    {"field":"ingredients","gte":"bakepulver","lte":"bakepulver"},
    {"field":"ingredients","gte":"hvetemel","lte":"hvetemel"}
];
var searchObject =      
    {"field":"ingredients","gte":"bakepulver","lte":"bakepulver"};

var indexOfSearchResult;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var checkEqualBool = true;
    for (var key in array[i]) {
        if(array[i][key]!=searchObject[key]){
            checkEqualBool = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(checkEqualBool){
        indexOfSearchResult = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use old method of comparing object, by *stringify* it. try to review this one

```js
var x = [{
  "field": "ingredients",
  "gte": "egg",
  "lte": "egg"
}, {
  "field": "ingredients",
  "gte": "bakepulver",
  "lte": "bakepulver"
}, {
  "field": "ingredients",
  "gte": "hvetemel",
  "lte": "hvetemel"
}];
var control = {
  "field": "ingredients",
  "gte": "bakepulver",
  "lte": "bakepulver"
};

function getIndex(arr, key) {
  var got = false,
    result = -1;
  arr.every(function(e, i) {
    if (JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(key)) {
      console.log('match found');
      result = i;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(getIndex(x, control));
```

Comment: this works only if the properties have the same order, which is not guarantied with objects.

Comment: ya that's the main drawback. exactly agree with you @NinaScholz